# Ember-data cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

**I'm trying to get data from api server with ember-data ,i added ember-data to ember starter-kit.**

Getting with

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'emberjs/ember.js',
    host     : 'https://api.github.com/repos'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter'
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('pull');
  }
});

App.Pull = DS.Model.extend({
    url : DS.attr(),
    title  : DS.attr(),
    body  : DS.attr()
});
```

Giving the same error for every request. then i try with github, it gives the same error.

Api that i connected: [Github api](https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/pulls)

> Error while processing route: index Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: At which line the error is shown?

Comment: Error while processing route: index Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember expects a pluralised root object when returning multiple results, in this case `pulls`, i.e

```
{
    "pulls": [...]
}
```

As you're working with an api you don't control you'll need to change the data into embers expected format with a modified Serializer like so:

**/app/serializers/pull.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        if(Array.isArray(payload)) {
            return {"pulls": payload };
        }
        return payload;
    }
});
```

Information on serializer:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html